# How to record parameter values of a method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I am currently developing a really big app. We are now facing the problem of Unit Testing everything in it.

I am trying to record all the interactions in methods and classes during execution time to have inputs and outputs to compare.

Yeah, i know it is not the properly way of doing Unit Testing but we need to do it quickly. We are already working with Mockito/PowerMockito/JUnit.

Already tried AOP and AspectJ but the problem is having to create new files for each class we have.

I was thinking in a way of intercepting the execution flow layer or somewhat to just write then dynamically in a Json file the input + dependencies values and output of method and classes invoked.

Any clues?

Comment: 1) That's not what unit testing is, and 2) you should write the code from the beginning to be testable. If your code is too coupled or doesn't expose enough interfaces, you won't be able to test it. Using AspectJ and PowerMockito you're only masking the real problem: non-testable (aka bad practices) code.

Comment: > *"Yeah, i know it is not the properly way of doing Unit Testing but we need to do it quickly."* - This is the wrong approach: what you do "quickly" now will stand in your way and slow you down in near future.

Answer (score 0):

> We are now facing the problem of Unit Testing everything in it.

Unittest do **not** test code, unittest verify *public observable behavior* that has justification from your requirements.

*public observable behavior* does not nessessarrily mean `public` methods but *observable from outside the code under test*. This is *return values* and *communication with dependencies*.